# How can we convert list of list to map ? (Elixir)

Tags: data-structures, elixir

I have a list which consists of [A, B, C, D, E] and A has a list of values [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] similarly B has a list of values [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
Date,SKU,Unit Price,Quantity,Total Price
2019-01-01,Death by Chocolate,180,5,900
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,1,150
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,1,150
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,3,450
2019-01-01,Death by Chocolate,180,1,180
2019-01-01,Vanilla Double Scoop,80,3,240
2019-01-01,Butterscotch Single Scoop,60,5,300
2019-01-01,Vanilla Single Scoop,50,5,250
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,5,750
```

Something like this but what I want is to create a map where the header is equal to values corresponding to it.

The expected output looks something like this:-

```
[%{date: '2019-01-01',SKU: 'Death by Chocolate', price: 50, quantity: 3},
    %{date: '2019-01-01',SKU: 'Cake Fudge', price: 150, quantity: 3}]
```

I'm having a difficulty converting something like this.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It looks like a CSV. If it is coming from a CSV source, maybe you can look into [NimbleCSV](https://hex.pm/packages/nimble_csv).

Comment: No, I'm reading it from normal text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific use case a CSV parser will do what you're looking for, even if your file extension isn't `.csv`.

If you're just looking to use one list as keys for other lists, you can combine `Enum.zip/2` with `Map.new/1` to zip your header list with a row list and create a map (depending on file size you may want to work with streams instead of lists).

```rb
iex> [headers | rows] = do_some_parsing(text)
iex> headers
["Date", "SKU", "Unit Price", "Quantity", "Total Price"]
iex> rows
[["2019-01-01", "Death by Chocolate", 180, 5, 900],
 ["2019-01-01", "Cake Fudge", 150, 1, 150],
 ...]
iex> Enum.map(rows, fn row -> headers |> Enum.zip(row) |> Map.new() end)
[%{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "SKU" => "Death by Chocolate", "Unit Price" => 180, "Quantity" => 5, "Total Price" => 900},
 %{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "SKU" => "Cake Fudge", "Unit Price" => 150, "Quantity" => 1, "Total Price" => 150},
 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed